# Python findall() start digit and end word

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have this string

```
procesor = "2x2.73 GHz Mongoose M5 & 2x2.50 GHz Cortex-A76 & 4x2.0 GHz Cortex-A55"
```

and I need this CPU core list by using the re.findall()

```
Out:['2x2.73 GHz', '2x2.50 GHz', '4x2.0 GHz']
```

Please help me. I'm stuck here:

```
re.findall('(\d+[A-Za-z])',procesor)
Out[1]: ['2x', '2x', '4x']
```

Comment: You don't have any quantifiers after `[A-Za-z]`, which means it will only match one character.

Comment: For building regex and test them, you can use [Pythex](https://pythex.org/)

Comment: Hi Matty, did you try out [my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64948484/11329890)?  If yes, please kindly accept/upvote.

Comment: Hi Ryszard, all three answers helped me. Thanks (Vďaka ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```py
re.findall(r'\d+x\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*GHz', procesor)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/9T7HOu/1/).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  x                        'x'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  GHz                      'GHz'
```

If you need it case insensitive:

```py
re.findall(r'\d+x\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*GHz', procesor, re.I)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a more human readable format `[0-9]` represents one digit:

```py
processor = "2x2.73 GHz Mongoose M5 & 2x2.50 GHz Cortex-A76 & 4x2.0 GHz Cortex-A55"
re.findall(r'[0-9]+x[0-9]+.[0-9]* GHz', processor)
```

Returns:

```py
['2x2.73 GHz', '2x2.50 GHz', '4x2.0 GHz']
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex-pattern can helps you: `([\d.]+)\s?[xX]\s?([\d.]+)\s?GHz` or insentitive case `(?i)([\d.]+)\s?x\s?([\d.]+)\s?GHz`

See the sample in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nkbdt6/2)!

Append this to your Python source:

```
processor  = """2x2.73 GHz Mongoose M5 & 2x2.50 GHz Cortex-A76 & 4x2.0 GHz Cortex-A55"""
CPU_Cores = re.findall("([\d.]+)\s?[xX]\s?([\d.]+)\s?GHz", processor)
print (CPU_Cores)
```

Output

```
[('2', '2.73'), ('2', '2.50'), ('4', '2.0')]
```

**Explaination**

`([\d.]+)\s?[xX]\s?([\d.]+)\s?GHz`

- The first group `([\d.]+)` matches first real-number.
- `\s?[xX]\s?` matches  `x`, `x` , `x`,  `X`, `X` , `X`.
- The second group `([\d.]+)`matches second real-number.
- `\s?` is optional that matches `whitespace character` or nothing.
- `GHz` matches literally word GHz.